# Scrapy Selector only getting the first element in for loop

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I don't understand why the following code doesn't work when using Scrapy Selector.

In scrapy shell (to be easily replicable, but the issue remains the same in a spider):

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector

body = '''<html>
<body>
  <li>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>9</p>
  </li>
</body>
</html>'''

sel = Selector(text=body, type="html")

for elem in sel.xpath('//body'):
    first = elem.xpath('.//li/p[1]/text()').get()
    print(first)
```

And it prints:

```
1
```

while it should be printing:

```
1
4
7
```

Any idea on how to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There maybe a chance that you're using the .get() method to fetch the data which you can replace with .getall(). This method will give you all the data in list format through which you can get your desired data with help of python slicing.

Or in other way there maybe a change that class name is differ in each "li" tag or you may have to use pass the class="" in your xpath URL.

**Note:** Rather then fetching data with path: "elem.xpath('.//li/p[1]/text()').get()" you can simply get all data by using "elem.xpath('.//li/p/text()').getall()" and then you can put the manipulation logic over the list data which is the easiest way if you don't get your desired output.

Comment: The getall method is working just fine. "first = elem.xpath('.//li/p[1]/text()').getall()"

Comment: By this you can get all the desired data in list of strings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).